# Gravity Forms closes my popup on Validation Error

Tags: ajax, javascript, plugin-gravity-forms

I am having an issue with Gravity Forms.  A user on my site can open a contact form in a popup menu by clicking a 'contact' button. The form is just in an absolute div that I show/hide on the contact button. If a user does not fill out a required field, obviously the form does not validate and does not send.  My issue is that if the form does not validate, the popup closes and the user has no idea that their form did not go through.  They would have to reopen the popup to see the default gravity forms message saying "this field is required", how can I stop Gravity Forms 'submit' from closing the popup if the form does not validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make sure you're loading the form with AJAX enabled. I'm assuming that the the form is actually refreshing the entire page (hence the popup closing). If you enable AJAX, only the form should be refreshed and the popup's visibility should not be impacted.